# Set read/write access to Firebase Realtime database only from my NestJS Firebase function

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase project, where I have a NestJS application deployed to Firebase functions. In this very same project I have an Angular application deployed to Firebase hosting, and finally I have a Firebase Realtime Database in the same Firebase project.

I'd like to make the latter be only readable/writeable from my NestJS application (so no direct access from the Angular app, or from anywhere else). What kind of Realtime Database rules should I set up?

Currently I have the following rules (which are obviously not good):

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
  }
}
```

My ideal approach would be to allow everything from the following domain + path:
`https://us-central1-my-firebase-function.cloudfunctions.net/api/` or allow everything from my Firebase function only.

Is there an easy, clean and secure way to do this?

Thanks for the tips in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
  {
      "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "auth.uid != null && root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('isAdmin').val() === true"
      }
    }
```

1st for your NestJS application user , Add as Admin and then check the following

Comment: Could you elaborate on the ```Add as Admin``` part? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you access Firebase services from within Cloud Functions you're using the Admin SDK. And this SDK bypasses any security rules you've set.

So to disallow all client-side access, you can set your security rules to:

```js
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false
  }
}
```

And then your code in Cloud Functions will still be able to access the data, as it bypasses these rules due to using the Admin SDK.

Comment: Sounds great, but currently I'm reaching out to the Realtime database from my NestJS app with Axios HTTP requests. If I understand you correctly, I need to drop Axios and implement the Admin SDK. I assume, it has the same/similar capabilities when writing and querying data to/from Realtime database as Axios has.

Comment: I had made the assumption that your code runs server-side given the mention of Node.js and "or allow everything from my Firebase function only". If that is not the case, you'll have to consider other options. One of those could be to [implement App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check).

Comment: Yes, it is running server side, yet I’m able to use Axios to read/write the Realtime database. But I guess it won’t work anymore as soon as I set the aforementioned rules.

Comment: Aha, so you're accessing Realtime Database through its REST API? That makes a big difference, so I'd recommend making that more explicit in your question. --- One option through that API and still use the approach from my answer here would be to pass the OAuth credentials for a collaborator on the calls. Those get collaborator level access to the database, so still bypass the security rules.

Comment: Do you mean that I should setup the email/password signin method under Authentication in Firebase console, then register a user manually, then I should pass the user/pass combo in the header of each REST API call?

Comment: A collaborator is somebody you added to the [users and permissions](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/iam) tab of your project. It is not a Firebase user, but a Google account. If you pass their OAuth token to the REST API, that request will run as that collaborator. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth